# Undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass in atom_feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Disclaimer:** I'm *very* new to Ruby on Rails.

Here is the error I am getting when attempting to generate a feed:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

**Extracted source (around line #2):**

```
atom_feed do |feed|
    feed.title "Who bought #{@product.title}"

    feed.updated @latest_order.try(:updated_at)
```

**Application trace:**

```
app/views/products/who_bought.atom.builder:2:in `block in _app_views_products_who_bought_atom_builder__3166274680323093135_70240865825480'
app/views/products/who_bought.atom.builder:1:in `_app_views_products_who_bought_atom_builder__3166274680323093135_70240865825480'
```

This is my first time working with atom_feed - so I am really not sure what to look for here. What I have appears to be straight from the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" Am I missing something?

Comment: `feed` is nil. Check your atom feed configuration.

Answer (score 1):

### Should be:

**CODING :**

```
before_action :
set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :who_bought]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a script I did not list - inside the products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /products
  # GET /products.json
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /products/new
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  # GET /products/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /products
  # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /products/1
  # PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def who_bought
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @latest_order = @product.orders.order(:updated_at).last
    if stale?(@latest_order)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.atom
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
end
```

The who_bought method, was listed under the private methods and I had also forgotten the '`@`' symbol in `@latest_order`

Answer (score 0):

Your @product variable is nil. Did you defined it? Does the particular product exist?
Try to output it into console: `logger.info @product.inspect`